# How does one specialize a template for all non-array types?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a template my_type. I want it to have general functionality, to have a few extra functions when T is not an array and to have others when T is an array.

Let's say I have the following template:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class<T> {
public:
    int f1(); // This function is available for all T
    int f2(); // This function is available when T is not an array
    int f3(); // This function is available when T is an array
}
```

So if I try:

```
my_class<int> c1; my_class<int[3]> c2;
c1.f1(); c2.f1(); // both fine
c1.f2(); c2.f3(); // both fine
c1.f3(); c2.f2(); // both should give a compile error
```

I am aware `std::unique_ptr` does this internally. So how does it do it?

Comment: You can try looking at some `std::unique_ptr` implementation.

Comment: I tried but I don't know how it works.

Comment: @VTT When one specializes a template implementation, will it inherit the functions in the general implementation or will those have to be copied? In the second case it's easy. (I am checking it myself now)

Comment: Okay, it's the latter. Then I guess I answered my own question. I just have to polish a code sample.

Comment: It is actually possible to specialize everything or just a particular method.

Comment: @VTT Okay, I figured that out after all. But when I specialize how can I preserve some methods while removing others?

Comment: You can mark unwanted method as deleted in specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way, using `enable_if`. Note also the use of a base class to capture all common behaviour.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct my_base
{
    int f1();
};

template<class T, typename Enable = void> 
class my_class;

template<class T> 
class my_class<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value>>
: public my_base<T>
{
public:
    int f3(); // This function is available when T is an array
};

template <typename T>
class my_class<T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_array<T>::value>> 
: public my_base<T>
{
public:
    int f2(); // This function is available when T is not an array
};

int main()
{
    auto a = my_class<int[]>();
    a.f1();
//    a.f2();
    a.f3();

    auto na = my_class<int>();
    na.f1();
    na.f2();
//    na.f3();
}
```

Comment: THIS <3 Funny how the implementation I found did not use this.

Comment: Any ways on making the base class uninstantiable, and thus requiring users of this code to only use the derived class?

Comment: you can make the base constructor protected

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thank you. I will accept this answer as it's a more elegant solution than my own.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured it out myself. The following code will do the exact thing I have asked for.

```
template<typename T>
class my_class {
public:
        int f1() { return 1; }
        int f2() { return 2; }
};

template<typename T>
class my_class<T[]> {
public:
        int f1() { return 1; }
        int f3() { return 3; }
};
```

Note that the implementation of the common function (`f1`) had to be copied. Now is there a way to use a single implementation? (note that it is NOT as simple as a `return 1;` like in the example code and thus I can't separate functionality into a non-template function)

Comment: The most simple way to share `f1()` is by using a common public base class.

Comment: @johannes Thank you, the other answer has already shown that.